# Why is discrete space ``discrete"

Tags: general-topology

I want to know why a discrete topological space is `discrete"? I looked up some references books, but found nothing about this question. In my opinion,`discrete" is nearly related to ``discontinuous".  In order to answer this question, I figure out a corresponding assertion:

---

**Let  $f$ be a non-constant map from topological space $ X$ to discrete space $Y.$ Then $f$ is continuous, if and only if $X$ is  a discrete space.**

---

The sufficiency part of the foregoing assertion is trivial. But I do not know if its necessity part is valid. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A better version would read: *Any function $f:X\to Y$ to any topological space $Y$ is continuous, iff $X$ is discrete*. In general *Discrete Math* is in some vague sense the opposite of *Continuous Math* (analysis and such). Not unexpectedly that is one sweeping generalization. Methods from one side of the aisle are applied to questions from the other at leisure.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. I do not know why you modified my assertion like that. I want to give some conditions which yields that, even  ordinary continuous function, like $f(x)=\sin(x) $ from $\mathbb{R} $ to $\mathbb{R}$ will be disretizied  to be discontinuous, if we modified the topology of the codomain.

Comment: I was looking for a modification that gives a true statement :-)

Comment: Your latest addition (where the assumptions only mention a GIVEN function $f$) only means that $X$ cannot be connected. You need to quantify over the set of ALL functions to force $X$ to be discrete.

Comment: For example, let $X=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ with the usual topology, and $Y=\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology. The non-constant function $f$ that maps all of $[0,1]$ to $0$ and all of $[2,3]$ to $1$ is continuous. Yet $X$ is not discrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you wrote is false, since a constant $f$ is continuous, no matter what topology you apply to $Y$.

Comment: Oh, you are right! How about if $f$ is not constant function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because such a space (X,T) is metrizable by the discrete metric and then  the basis can be taken as the collection of all open balls B(x,1/2) ={x} for all x in X.